# Why my select with indexed field and non-indexed field sometimes take long time

Tags: sql, mysql, mariadb

I have a big table (~30M rows), it usually run fast( 5-6ms per request). Sometimes one request take a lot of time (something like 60sec).

Here the table structure :

```sql
CREATE TABLE table (
  id int(11) NOT NULL,
  A int(11) NOT NULL,
  B varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  C tinyint(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `table`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (id),
  ADD KEY A (A),
  ADD KEY B (B);
```

Cardinality is 2M for index A and 1k for index B.

Here my request :

```sql
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE A = someAvalue
    AND B = 'some B value'
    AND C = 0
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

And the result of explain :

```
id|select_type|table|type|possible_keys|key|key_len|ref  |rows|Extra 
1 |SIMPLE     |table|ref |A,B          |B  |34     |const|1   |Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort
```

`key_len` and `rows` are not relevent on this case because it's from an exemple query

If i remove `AND C = 0` request run a normal amount of time. It seems that this request go wild when index A and B return no value.

So here my question : why adding a non indexed field in this case can make the request run in 60+ sec instead of some millisecond ?

Comment: What does the execution plan tell you about this?

Comment: i've edited the question

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your question** by editing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few potential reasons that could explain this behavior:

- Loss of Index Efficiency: Your query is initially using indexes on columns A and B. However, when you add the non-indexed condition C = 0, the database can no longer efficiently filter rows using just the indexes. It has to check the C column for each row that matches the conditions on A and B. This process can be time-consuming, particularly if the number of rows matching A and B is large.
- Full Table Scan or Row-by-Row Filtering: Since C is not indexed, the database might perform a full table scan or a row-by-row check after filtering with A and B, significantly increasing the query time, especially for a large table like yours.
- Query Execution Plan Changes: The inclusion of a non-indexed field can alter the execution plan generated by the database's query optimizer. The optimizer might choose a less efficient path due to the added complexity of filtering on a non-indexed field.
- Filesort for Ordering: The EXPLAIN output indicates the use of "Using filesort," which is an operation that can be slow, especially if it's working on a large intermediate result set. The sorting operation becomes more complex with the additional non-indexed field.
- Inefficient Use of Resources: When you add an extra condition, the query might require more memory and CPU time to process the additional filtering and sorting, which could slow down the execution in resource-constrained environments.
- Data Skew: If the distribution of values in C is skewed (i.e., very few rows have C = 0), the database might end up scanning a significant portion of the table to find the relevant rows, leading to longer execution times.

Comment: thanks for giving me these leads to explores, it really help me, it seem that it was doing a  full table scan or a row by row filtering in some case.

Answer (score 1):

> Why my select with indexed field and non-indexed field sometimes take
> long time?

The first important issue is the usage of MyISAM storage Engine, please switch to InnoDB. MyISAM supports table lock only even for select statements.

See [What are the main differences between InnoDB and MyISAM?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-are-the-main-differences-between-innodb-and-myisam)

Secondly add the following index on your table.

```
alter table your_table add index c_a_b(C,A,B)
```

Comment: I only search the 'why' here, I've already modifing my request to prevent this behavior.
unfortunatly i can't change engine storage that easily for other reason.
I can't add an index either for now as it will lock my table for 20-30min straight

Answer (score 0):

Ekans, Strategically placed parenthesis use should avoid the table scan for C = 0.

SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE ( A = someAvalue
AND B = 'some B value' )
AND C = 0
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1;

please verify in your version of MySQL and let us know how much time this solution takes.
And post the EXPLAIN please for comparison.